# Select elements from a list according to indices

Tags: list, prolog

Is there a way to define a predicate that behaves (more or less) like this:

```
% nths(?Indices, ?List, ?Nths)
nths([], _, []).
nths([N|Ns], List, [E|Es]) :-
    nth0(N, List, E),
    nths(Ns, List, Es).
```

but without an explicit loop, and without a lambda? I have the feeling that it should be possible to do it with `maplist` maybe, or `findall`, but I couldn't figure it out...

(It is of course only true for a *List* that is a list, *Indices* that are integers [0, list_length), and all *Nths* members of *List*)

On the other hand, this is a very short and obvious definition....

Comment: The particular argument order does not permit to use maplist/3 directly. You need therefore an intermediary definition to reorder the arguments. library(lambda) avoids that extra definition.

Comment: @false I have a somewhat irrational fear of lambdas altogether. Getting over it won't hurt in the long term I suppose.

Comment: if indices are ordered, non-decreasing, this really *ought* to be done with a loop - in one pass over the list.

Comment: @WillNess No, the indices are in random (unknown) order. Both indices and original list are not too big and not a performance issue yet.

Comment: @Boris: Seems you have *rigor labda* (sic), that very disease that makes you struck in the presence of lambdas. I can somewhat understand it: The variable handling is different to functional languages, since variables serve a somewhat different role in Prolog.

Comment: @false :) But to be honest, my main goal is always: write clear, concise code. Lambdas can help (at least in the languages I have encountered them), but I find it difficult to know when to stop and use another way of expressing myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `findall/3` suffices:

```
nths(Ns, List, Es) :-
    findall(E, (member(N, Ns), nth0(N, List, E)), Es).
```

`maplist` can also do this, but it needs an auxiliary predicate:

```
nth0r(L, N, X) :- nth0(N, L, X).
nths(Ns, List, Es) :-
    maplist(nth0r(List), Ns, Es).
```

Comment: But this version does not work properly for constraints. That is, constraints occurring in List.

Comment: @false: posted a version with `maplist/3`.

Comment: why not use `findall` instead of `bagof`? It does produce `[]` instead of failing, and we don't need to concern ourselves with the free vars.

Comment: @WillNess: I thought `bagof` would be needed for the free variable, but you're right, `findall` does the job as well.